# getting the name of the variable with the maximum value in anylogic

Tags: variables, max, anylogic

In anylogic, I have some variables(more than 2) and I want to know which of them has the maximum value? How can I do that?
where can I save the name of the maximum variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting the maximum value of a number of values is not an AnyLogic problem but a general coding problem which stackoverflow probably has hundreds of answers for.

In AnyLogic, you could add all your variables to a statistics object. Then call `myStatisticsObject.max()` to get the maximum.

To save that in a new variables, call `newVariable = mtStatistics.max()`

cheers

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful.